# Classify POI where poi is based on ~Classification and a ~UserAttribute

Tags: r, lidr

Can I use a multi-criteria-poi when calling `classify_poi()`?  While I am really trying to classify points based on matching `~Classification` and `~UserAttribute` values, the code below throws the same error.  It does work when poi is either based on `~Classification` or based on `~Z`, but not both.

```r
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las  <- readLAS(LASfile, filter = "-keep_random_fraction 0.1")
poi <- ~Classification != LASGROUND & ~Z > 15
las <- classify_poi(las, LASHIGHVEGETATION, poi = poi)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost correct. The syntax of a formula in R can contain only one `~`

```r
poi <- ~Classification != LASGROUND & Z > 15
```

Comment: Thank you.  That fixed it.